# VSCode - Ctrl + Alt + L adds weird character. Need to get rid of it

Tags: visual-studio-code, special-characters, key-bindings, code-formatting

I seem to have enabled an awkward mode in my VS Code editor that i cant seem to backtrack.

I initially set my Ctrl + Alt + L keybinding to format the code in my editor. Which it initially did. After that - I don't know - I must have pressed some set of keys (maybe shift + something, **but I'm not sure**), and now whenever I use that key bind. It instead enters a tiny dot like character.

`'royalblue̥̥̥̥',` <- Like that.

I don't know what this character is and how it came. But I can't get rid of it.

> How do I get rid of it?

**UPDATE: The issue seems to have been solved, I don't know how. Apparently, when I restarted my machine, the issue was gone (maybe others who come across this can try doing the same). I am, however, keeping this question open, in case someone encounters this and can't get rid of it. Perhaps, an answer may arise and we can finally find out what the issue was all along.**

Comment: Unfortunately not resolved for me. If you have found any solution/explanation please reply!

Comment: This mostly happens when you change your keyboard language. Changing the keyboard language to ENG ( US Keyboard ) solves the issue for me.

Comment: This is still an issue on Windows 10 + VS Code (1.38.1)

Comment: See also the [keyboard troubleshooting wiki](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I can confirm that this is due to keyboard language setup. My machine's language was set to **English (India)** and this same issue started since then. I switched to **English (UK)** and it got fixed.

I am not sure if this issue is specific to **English (India)** keyboard language, though. I have **English (US)** and **Urdu (India)** keyboard languages as well and I don't face this issue with them.

Comment: Doesn't resolve the issue for me.

Comment: On window 11, switch to uk, fixed for me. i was using English (India)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue on Windows 11 when pressing `Ctrl + Alt + L` in VSCode. Previous answers and the following steps on Windows 11 have helped me to resolve it.

1. Go to Settings > Time & Language > **Language & Region**
2. Go to **Language Options** after clicking on the three dots menu on the right side of the selected language.
3. Go to **Installed Keyboards** and add a keyboard **(US - QWERTY)** and remove the other ones (English (India) - QWERTY).
4. Done.